# Woocommerce location of `<ul>` of archive-products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to customize my `archive-products.php` of my `woocommerce`-shop. The products are apparently list elements inside an `<ul>`. Now I want to change it but I can't find the `<ul>` anywhere. I looked inside the `content-products.php` but here I only find the `<li>` elements.

Can someone help me out? How can I get rid of the `<ul>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove those by overriding WooCommerce template files `loop/loop-start.php` and `loop/loop-end.php`.

Comment: Thanks! That was what I was looking for, yet so simple :-)